# MongoDB Aggregation Matching By Reference Document

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm trying to create a system to track split tests on my app.
Each user is assigned a int value, representing their status, I then store each visit, with visits having a reference to user documents.

The query bellow was suppose to give me the average online per day for users who have the test_subject field as 0.

Here is my current scheema:

```
class Visits(Document):
year = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
month = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().month)
day = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().day, unique_with=('month', 'year'))
visits = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Visit'))


class Posts(Document):
year = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
month = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().month)
day = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().day, unique_with=('month', 'year'))
posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Post'))


class Visit(Document):
user = ReferenceField('User')
time_spent = IntField(default=0)


class Post(Document):
id = IntField(primary_key=True)
user = ReferenceField('User')
number_of_comments = IntField(default=0)
number_of_clicks = IntField(default=0)


class User(Document):
id = IntField(primary_key=True)
created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
test_subject = IntField(default="0")
```

Here is my current query:

```
def aa(request):
year = datetime.datetime.now().year
month = datetime.datetime.now().month
result = Visits._get_collection().aggregate([
{
    "$unwind": "$visits"
},
{
    "$match": {"visits.user.test_subject" : 0}
},
{"$group": {
    "_id": {
        "day": "$day"
    },
    "visits": {
        "$avg": "$visits.time_spent"
    }
}}
])
return result
```

For some reason the output is always an empty array.

**EDIT**

Visits Collection:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5397661f88dba01cd8156eea" }, 
"year" : 2014,
"month" : 6,
"day" : 10,
"visits" : [ { "$oid" : "5397660b88dba01cd8156ee9" }, { "$oid" :        "539766b988dba01cd8156eeb" }, { "$oid" : "5397670088dba01cd8156eec" } ] }
```

Visit Collection:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5397660b88dba01cd8156ee9" }, "user" : 2, "time_spent" : 0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "539766b988dba01cd8156eeb" }, "user" : 2, "time_spent" : 0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5397670088dba01cd8156eec" }, "user" : 3, "time_spent" : 0 }
```

User Collection:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "created_at" : { "$date" : "2014-06-10T21:59:37.417+0100" }, "test_subject" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 3, "created_at" : { "$date" : "2014-06-10T21:59:37.417+0100" }, "test_subject" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has no joins and you can't aggregate data from 3 separate collections.

Your problem is that your creating separate collections when you are probably trying to embed the documents inside one collection

Your `Post` and `Visit` and `User` classes should inherit from `EmbeddedDocument` not `Document`. That way your Visits collection will have embedded documents and you can then run your aggregation on that collection.

Comment: Changed the default value to 0, droped all tables and retried, still outputing the same error. :(

Comment: @EduardoAlves can you post your collection in JSON from MongoDB?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm used to relational databases and this seems all very weird to me. The idea of creating refrences was to avoid redundancy, so both posts and visits all refrenced the same user. Is this a bad plan when using mongoDB? Thanks again!

Comment: Storing the objects this way is MongoDB is not really efficient (think about updating user in all visits). For data that is inherently relational RDBMS can be a better solution. It's a balancing act - no redundancy (normalized data) vs speed (no joins).